# "error: conversion to non-scalar type requested" when using structs and malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I've been having this issue for a few hours and have pinpointed it down to this simple bit of code. Can anyone give me some insight?

```
typedef struct test{
    //I get an error regardless of what's in here
}TESTS;

int main(){
    TESTS thing = (TESTS)malloc(sizeof(TESTS));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, you need to assign it to a `TESTS*`:

```
TESTS* thing = malloc(sizeof(TESTS));
```

Comment: How. How did I spend all this time on something so simple, that I really already knew. Thank you.

Comment: :) Happens to all of us. Glad I could help!

Comment: It would be better to remove the cast entirely.

Comment: @R.. - Cast removed. My C is rusty, didn't remember the preferred idiom.